# Text/Regex/TDFA/NewDFA/Engine.hs:13:33: parse error on input ‘#’

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to run a simple Haskell program using `TDFA`. The program is as follows:

```
import Control.Monad      
import Data.Array  
import qualified Data.Text as T  
import Text.Regex  
import Text.Regex.TDFA      
import Text.Regex.Base  

str = "abbbbaab" :: String     
regex = "(a+)(b+)" :: String   

main = do  
 if str (=~) :: regex then putStrLn "matched" else putStrLn "no matches"
```

when I try to run the above program using the command like: `ghc test.hs -o test` and then I am getting the following error (`test.hs` is the Haskell program which contains the above code):

```
Text/Regex/TDFA/NewDFA/Engine.hs:13:33: parse error on input ‘#’
```

Note that I have the latest version of `TDFA` installed on my `pc`. I did it by following ways:

```
ghc --make -o setup Setup.hs
```

Also, I did the following:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/regex-tdfa-master$ sudo cabal install regex-tdfa    
[sudo] password for user:    
Resolving dependencies...    
All the requested packages are already installed:    
regex-tdfa-1.2.2
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

I even tried it with the `Makefile` which I got from [TDFA's github repository](https://github.com/ChrisKuklewicz/regex-tdfa):

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/regex-tdfa-master$ make    
ghc -o setup --make ./Setup.hs
./setup clean    
cleaning...    
./setup configure --prefix=/Users/user/local/devel/trl --enable-library-profiling --user        
Configuring regex-tdfa-1.2.2...    
./setup build    
Building regex-tdfa-1.2.2...    
Preprocessing` library regex-tdfa-1.2.2...    
[ 1 of 23] Compiling Text.Regex.TDFA.NewDFA.Uncons ( Text/Regex/TDFA/NewDFA/Uncons.hs, dist/build/Text/Regex/TDFA/NewDFA/Uncons.o )     
...........(Skipped to make the things short here)..............................    
[23 of 23] Compiling Text.Regex.TDFA  ( Text/Regex/TDFA.hs, dist/build/Text/Regex/TDFA.o )    
Text/Regex/TDFA.hs:60:8:   
    Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Base’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘regex-base-0.93.2@regex_47KXx9dLqeO8MNJeizLKhP’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Text/Regex/TDFA/ByteString.hs:24:8:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Base.Impl’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘regex-base-0.93.2@regex_47KXx9dLqeO8MNJeizLKhP’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Text/Regex/TDFA/CorePattern.hs:37:8:
   Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.RWS’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘mtl-2.2.1@mtl_Aue4leSeVkpKLsfHIV51E8’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Text/Regex/TDFA/ReadRegex.hs:13:8:
    `Could not find module ‘Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec’`
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘parsec-3.1.9@parse_EE5NO1mlYLh4J8mgDEshNv’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Text/Regex/TDFA/String.hs:23:8:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike’`
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘regex-base-0.93.2@regex_47KXx9dLqeO8MNJeizLKhP’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Text/Regex/TDFA/TDFA.hs:10:8:`
    Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.State’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘mtl-2.2.1@mtl_Aue4leSeVkpKLsfHIV51E8’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.    

Makefile:16: recipe for target 'build' failed    
make: *** [build] Error 1    
user@user-VirtualBox:~/regex-tdfa-master$
```

However, nothing worked. Hence, any help would be so appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are compiling your program from within Regex-TDFA source code. I am able to reproduce your problem if I do `cabal unpack regex-tdfa && cd regex-tdfa-1.2.2 && ghc --make test.hs`.

The error happens because when GHC finds Regex-TDFA source files in the current directory, it just picks them and tries to compile, as if they were ordinary source files belonging to your project. However, Regex-TDFA cannot be built with simple `ghc --make`: in order to build it, you have to run cabal first. Cabal will read `regex-tdfa.cabal` file that contains the list of the necessary GHC extensions.

In particular, parse error happens because GHC extension `MagicHash` is missing (that's where the hash `#` comes from).

The "fix" is to move your `test.hs` to some other location: then GHC will use system package for Regex-TDFA.

Comment: `@skvadrik` Thank you so much, sir. it worked....I mean you know, what ?? I spent lot of times ..but the solution was just to move the `test.hs` file into other location also needs to have {-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-} at the beginning of the program. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Text/Regex/TDFA/NewDFA/Engine.hs:13:33: parse error on input ‘#’
> ```

On an initial note, this error points to [a module of the *regex-tdfa* package](https://github.com/ChrisKuklewicz/regex-tdfa/blob/f1b671946ee573f86d72484f3ab56487d456e735/Text/Regex/TDFA/NewDFA/Engine.hs), so you should have gotten it when building the package, rather than when building your `test.hs`, unless you were trying to build `test.hs` after putting it within the package source tree. In any case, line 13 of the mentioned file is:

```
import GHC.Prim(MutableByteArray#,RealWorld,Int#,sizeofMutableByteArray#,unsafeCoerce#)
```

The `#` names require the [`MagicHash` GHC extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.2-rc1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#the-magic-hash) to be enabled. As there is no `{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}` pragma at the beginning of the file, one should assume the extension is enabled through the `.cabal` file of the package, [and that is indeed the case](https://github.com/ChrisKuklewicz/regex-tdfa/blob/f1b671946ee573f86d72484f3ab56487d456e735/regex-tdfa.cabal#L63). That being so, your problem seems to be that you are attempting use the package modules straight from the source tree, without using an appropriate build tool such as [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/intro.html). (Note that if you did successfully run `cabal install regex-tdfa` there should be no need of dealing with the source tree: `ghc --make -o test test.hs` should be enough.)

P.S.: There is an error in your `test.hs`. The last line should be...

```
 if str =~ regex then putStrLn "matched" else putStrLn "no matches"
```

(I did manage to run it after this correction.)